# su using here document

Tags: linux, solaris

### file: test.sh

```
who
su superuser <<BELUGA
mysuperpassword
BELUGA
who
```

$ ./test.sh

just waits for input.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Most programs read the password from the current tty, not from stdin. (This also lets you do things such as pipe a binary file to a `su`'d command.)

Comment: Note that the su command would not execute the second who - even if you managed to get past the password issue.  It would either process the command given on its command line ('-c "command arg1 arg2"') or it would go interactive.  Commands asking for a password usually read from your tty rather than from standard input - which means you have to fake it out (probably with 'expect' and a pseudo-tty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the "expect" command for passing your username and password.

Note however that what you want to do there smells like a bad approach. Maybe we can halp you better if you elaborate a little more on your original problme you want to solve.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be a lot better to install/use sudo an with a configuration  config that allows NOPASSWD for the specific action you are trying to automate.

It will be much safer to allow a specific command via sudo then it would be to store your root password in a text file somewhere.

Comment: With Solaris, pfexec can be used instead of sudo, which isn't installed by default and has some limtations RBAC have not.

Comment: some limitations RBAC has not. sorry for the typos.

<useless rant> Why isn't edit allowed after such a short period of time ?</useless rant>

Comment: @jlliagre: If editing is locked out, I copy my original comment to the clipboard, delete the comment, create a new blank comment, paste the old comment from the clipboard, then edit it how I wanted to edit the original.

Answer (score 2):

Running a script as a user and having it upgrade its permissions to root is probably a bad idea. A better solution would be to run the script as root and have it downgrade its permissions as necessary:

```
#!/bin/sh
UN=user
whoami
sudo -u $UN whoami
```

When run as root (assuming `user` is a valid user) the output should be this:

```
root
user
```

However if you really want to have a script run as a user and be able to execute commands as root, there are 2 options that I know of.

1. Use sudo with stored password:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   whoami
   sudo -S -p "" whoami <<EOF
   mysuperpassword
   EOF
   ```

   Which will output (when run as 'user'):

   ```
   user
   root
   ```
2. Use sudo with no password.
   Add a list of the commands that you wish to run into the `/etc/sudoers` file by running `visudo` as root. For example, to allow `user` to run the commands `apache2ctl` and `whoami`, add the following:

   ```
   User_Alias SPECIAL = user
   Cmnd_Alias SPECIAL_COMMANDS = /usr/sbin/apache2ctl, /usr/bin/whoami
   SPECIAL ALL = NOPASSWD: SPECIAL_COMMANDS
   ```

   Or if you really trust `user`, if it's you for example, you can allow the user to execute any command without a password:

   ```
   user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
   ```

   Then when the following script is run by `user`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   whoami
   sudo whoami
   ```

   It will output:

   ```
   user
   root
   ```